# Jquery Ui range-slider content show on step

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a problem showing content based on the current step of jQuery UI range slider, for example on second step I need only show second-step-content

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNoXqX

HTML:

```
<span class="becky">first-step</span>
<span class="becky">second-step</span>
<span class="becky">third-step</span>
<span class="becky">fourth-step</span>
<span class="becky">fifth-step</span>

<div id="slider-2"></div>

 <!-- Content that I need show -->
 <span id="first-step-content">first-step-content</span> 
 <span id="second-step-content">econd-step-content</span>
 <span id="third-step-content">third-step-content</span> 
 <span id="fourth-step-content">fourth-step-conten</span>
 <span id="fifth-step-content">fifth-step-content</span>
```

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-2" ).slider({
        min: 4,
        max: 20,
        value: 12,
        step: 4,
        animate:"slow",
        orientation: "horizontal"
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a way to translate the scroll value to a span, using "first", "second" makes this difficult, as does using an `id`.  So add `data-` attributes, ie:

```
    <div id="slider-2"></div>
       <span data-step='1'>first-step-content</span> 
       <span data-step='2'>second-step-content</span>
       <span data-step='3'>third-step-content</span> 
       <span data-step='4'>fourth-step-conten</span>
       <span data-step='5'>fifth-step-content</span>  
    </div>
```

Next, listen to the [`.slide`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) event of the slider, which gives you the position in `ui.value` then use this to show the relevant content:

```
$("#slider-2").slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    value: 1,
    step: 1,
    animate:"slow",
    orientation: "horizontal",
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        // Convert value to index
        $("span[data-step]").hide()
        $("span[data-step='" + ui.value + "']").show()
    }
});
```

For simplicity, I've changed the min/max/value/step so there's a 1-1 with the value and data-step.  In practice, I'm assuming you've used min/max/step so that the scroll appears under the text - you just need to convert `ui.value` to `data-step` (or possibly use different values for data-step).

Comment: Love you :D i was looking for this for a long time thanks much

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you look for:

```
var val = $('#slider-2').slider("value");
if (val == 8){
   //show second-step content
}
```

additionally, if you have multiple values where you want to show/hide:

```
switch (val){
  case 8:
   //second-step
   break;
  case 12:
   //third-step
  break;
...
```